# Display of JavaScript files totally bolixed in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: javascript, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I've recently had Visual Studio Team System 2008 installed on my work system, and I can't use it to view (much less edit or debug) javascript files. If it opens the file at all--about 30% of the time--it's frequently cut off at the bottom. Additionally, the  display format is *awful*, not at all what it's supposed to be set up to be. Tiny font, weird colors,...ARRGHH!

I do have Visual Web Developer 2008 Express on this machine as well. It was on here before VSTS, and is still the associated program for .js extensions--which look & act exactly as I expect them to therein.

Is it possible to make VSTS play nice with javascript? How?

Answer (score 0):

I think your install or personal setting file may be corrupted. Maybe someone knows a trick to reset the Text Editor options dialog to all default values (I don't see a reset to defaults button in there). Otherwise it might need a reinstall (I'm sure you lost enough years of your life waiting for 2008 and SP1 to install the first time)